# How do I center a \Large equation in display mode?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, formatting, equations

I have an equation in display mode and would like to make it bigger using `\Large`, but the equation runs off the right side of the page while there is much room on the left side of the page.

The equation would fit if I could just center it.

How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, landscape]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

 {\Large$$\sum_{t_1=1}^{n}\binom{n}{t_1}+
 \sum_{t_1=1}^{n-1}\sum_{t_2=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{t_1,t_2}+\cdots+
 \sum_{t_1=1}^{1}\sum_{t_2=1}^{1}\cdots\sum_{t_n=1}^{1}
  \binom{n}{t_1,t_2, \dots, t_n}$$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could we have a Minimal Working Example (MWE) please: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: MWE especially relevant as, generally, displayed equations are centred ...

Comment: Please always make your examples _complete_ (in particular `\binom` is not defined by default) Your example does not centre as it is too large TeX reports `Overfull \hbox (63.78322pt too wide) detected at line 8`

Comment: Displayed equations are not centered completely. If they are small then they appear centered but if I have a long equation, it always runs off the right side.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What does this mean?

Comment: Displayed equations are centred completely, but if the equation is too big it will be flush against the left margin and any excess will spill into the right margin and, eventually, off the page. This is what happened to you. Adjust your margins, or your equation :)

Comment: It means that the equation is 63pt (so almost an inch or 2cm) too big to fit in the space which is why it overprints the right margin. TeX will centre equations that fit. Over-large content always sticks into the right margin.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it possible to change this so that it is always centered?

Comment: No, why? you can make the font smaller, or split the equation over two lines or change the margins globally or change the margins just for that equation, but you need to say what you want. presumably your real document does not consist just of a single equation.

Comment: Ok, How would I go about changing margins for just a single equation?

Answer (score 3):

I advise against using `\Large` equations, particularly if this creates too wide an object.

However, here's a possible solution that doesn't mess up the vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\[
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\Large
\[
\hidewidth
\sum_{t_1=1}^{n}\binom{n}{t_1}+
 \sum_{t_1=1}^{n-1}\sum_{t_2=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{t_1,t_2}+\dots+
 \sum_{t_1=1}^{1}\sum_{t_2=1}^{1}\cdots\sum_{t_n=1}^{1}
  \binom{n}{t_1,t_2, \dots, t_n}
\hidewidth
\]
\end{minipage}
\]
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Equations centre by default:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  


\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

aaaaa
%
{\large
\[
a+b+c+d=
a+b+c+d=
a+b+c+d=
a+b+c+d=
a+b+c+d
\]}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't center. It runs off to the right more than the left.

Comment: the above example is centred, I see you have added an example, let me run that and see...

Answer (score 1):

A small suggestion to start with: Don't use `\cdots`; since you're using the `amsmath` package, just use `\dots` and let the software work out which type of typographic ellipses are best.

If you want to typeset the equation in portrait mode at 12pt and a `\Large` relative font size, and if you're working with an "A4" paper size, you'll need to set the margins to `2cm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
{\Large
\[
\sum_{t_1=1}^{n}\binom{n}{t_1}+
\sum_{t_1=1}^{n-1}\sum_{t_2=1}^{n-1}
  \binom{n}{t_1,t_2}+\dots+
\sum_{t_1=1}^{1}\sum_{t_2=1}^{1}\dots\sum_{t_n=1}^{1}
  \binom{n}{t_1,t_2, \dots, t_n}
\]
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found \hspace*{-(value here)mm} works.

Comment: @AlJebr - There are quite a few postings on this site on how to widen the text block temporarily, say, in order to accommodate an extra-wide equation. The `\hspace*{...}` approach "works", but it suffers from the drawback that the equation won't necessarily be centered correctly -- at least not without engaging in a lot of trial and error work.

Comment: That is true. I found myself adjusting and just eyeing it. Are there simple methods similar to \hspace* that will work precisely?

Answer (score 0):

You have more possibilities:

- if equation is not numbered, than try:

`\begin{center}\Large
$\displaystyle a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{center}`

- if equation is numbered, than try:

`\begin{equation}\Large
\hspace*{-< x em>} a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}`

where `< x em>` you select so, that equation will be centered. Both suggestion are not tested, since you doesn't provide minimal working example, which would show your problem.

Comment: I tried this. It runs off to the right.

Comment: I don't belive you. Please, provide MWE, which will show this. If something is centered, than can not protrude out just in one side. Maybe you have something hidden there. For second case you not adjust properly. Tested.

Answer (score 0):

Alright.

Displayed equations are always centred. The exact middle of the equation shall be exactly half way between the margins if the equation is smaller than the margins. So, you can imagine, a centred equation will expand outwards until it comes up against the margins (I doubt this is precisely how TeX places its centred material, but obviously when you centre something, the centre of that thing should be mid-way between the two margins and the longer the equation, the closer the left- and rightmost ends of the equation shall be to the margins.) This is what TeX does. Thus:

```
\documentclass[12pt, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  x
\]
\[
  x + y
\]
\[
  \frac{1}{c^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}} \psi -
  \nabla^{2} \psi + \frac{m^{2}c^{2}}{\hbar^{2}} \psi = 0
\]
\[
  \overbrace{\int_{y_{1}}^{y_{2}} x(y) \, dy}^{A_{1}} +
  \overbrace{\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} y(x) \, dx}^{A_{2}} = x.y(x)
  \biggr|_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} = y.x(y) \biggr|_{y_{1}}^{y_{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your equation is as wide as the space between the margins,
obviously, it will fill up the entire space. If your equation is wider
than the margins, then the leftmost end of the equation will be forced
up against the margin and TeX will have no choice but to print the
rightmost end of the equation in the right hand margin and eventually
off the page.

Adding:

```
\[
  \int \frac{dx}{x^{2^{n}} + 1} = \sum_{k = 1}^{2^{n - 1}}
  \left\{\frac{1}{2^{n - 1}} \left[\sin\left(\frac{(2k -
          1)\pi}{2^{n}}\right) \arctan \left[\left(x -
          \cos\left(\frac{(2k - 1)\pi}{2^{n}}\right)\right) \csc
        \left( \frac{(2k - 1)\pi}{2^{n}}\right)\right]\right] -
    \frac{1}{2^{n}} \left[\cos \left(\frac{(2k - 1)\pi}{2^{n}}\right)
      \ln \left| x^{2} - 2x \cos \left(\frac{(2k -
            1)\pi}{2^{n}}\right) + 1\right| \right]\right\}
\]
```

[image]

TeX doesn't centre content on the page, it centres it between the
margins, between the margins is where the text goes. So, if your
equation is longer than the space between the margins, you have to
either modify the margins, or the equation.

It's not that the final equation isn't centred. The left-margin is the limit. Because the equation is too long, TeX has been forced to print the excess in the margin and off the page. If I have a 5 metre long garage and a 4.2 metre long car, I can park my car in the centre of my garage. The back of the car will be 40 cm from the back of the garage and the front of the car will be 40 cm from the front of the garage. If I have a 5 metre long car, the back of the car will be up against the back wall and the front of the car will be up against the door. If I have a 6 metre long car, the front of the car is going to stick out of the front of the garage. That's what's happened to you.

So:

---

Consider

```
\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
```

With `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\begin{document}` & `\end{document}` added to your MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

{\Large
  $$\sum_{t_{1} = 1}^{n} \binom{n}{t_{1}} + \sum_{t_{1} = 1}^{n-1}
  \sum_{t_{2} = 1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{t_{1},t_{2}} + \cdots + \sum_{t_{1} =
    1}^{1} \sum_{t_{2} = 1}^{1} \cdots \sum_{t_{n} = 1}^{1}
  \binom{n}{t_{1},t_{2}, \dots, t_{n}}$$
}

\end{document}
```

*Also* try `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$`, see: [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

[image]

Comment: I currently have margins at 2 inches.

Comment: Well change it to 2 inches then :)